# Source - Matan Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, kabbalat-hatorah

Is there a source that says that at Matan torah the Bnei Yisrael would receive the written Torah but because they sinned with the golden calf they received the oral Torah as well?

Please feel free to edit if need be.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in some information about why you suspect that such a source might exist?

Comment: Are you saying that the Oral Torah would have been included in the Written Torah had they not sinned with the Golden Calf or are you saying the Oral Torah would not have been given at all.

Comment: The oral Torah would not have been given at all

Comment: What would the written Torah look like? The way we have it is incomprehensible

Comment: I think had they not had sinned they would have attained the ability of understanding the written Torah without the need for the oral Torah.

Comment: @ezra Take a look at the second insight here http://dafyomi.co.il/shekalim/insites/sk-dt-016.htm -- he brings the beis levi who explains why and how the first luchos included all written and oral law, before the sin of the golden calf

Answer (score 5):

[Midrash Rabbah Shemot 46:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shemot_Rabbah.46.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) ([hebrewbooks link](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&pgnum=368))

> ‏...הִתְחִיל מִצְטַעֵר עַל שִׁבּוּר הַלּוּחוֹת, וְאָמַר לוֹ הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא אַל תִּצְטָעֵר בַּלּוּחוֹת‏ הָרִאשׁוֹנוֹת, שֶׁלֹא הָיוּ אֶלָּא עֲשֶׂרֶת הַדִּבְּרוֹת לְבָד, וּבַלּוּחוֹת הַשְּׁנִיִּים אֲנִי נוֹתֵן לְךָ שֶׁיְהֵא בָהֶם הֲלָכוֹת מִדְרָשׁ וְאַגָּדוֹת, הֲדָא הוּא דִכְתִיב: וְיַגֶּד לְךָ תַּעֲלֻמוֹת חָכְמָה כִּי כִפְלַיִם לְתוּשִׁיָּה,
>
> ...He started feeling bad that he broke the tablets, G-d told him: Do not feel bad about the first tablets, for they only contained the ten commandments, however in the second tablets i will give you, that they will have Halcaha Midrash and Agadah, this is what is said: (Job 11): I will tell you hidden wisdom for it shall be double comforting

---

See [here](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/91606/jewish/Ki-Sisa-Breaking-The-Luchos-A-Break-for-the-Jewish-People.htm) for an explanation from the Lubavitcher Rebbe why the first Luchos needed to be broken before the Oral Torah could be given.

Comment: Menachem, is this explanation incompatible with what you wrote in the comment above, from the Beis Halevi? It sounds like exactly opposite.

Comment: @MichoelR It is another perspective, based on the same midrash

Comment: K, just checking